# jQuery, CSS: Two divs, how can I make them "show"next to each other?

Tags: jquery, html, css

my client has asked me to make exactly what's happening in this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L2JgX/1/).

All I need is to make them appear next to each other.

As you see when one is fired it displays in the correct place, but when the other is fired, it pushes the other down.

How can I ensure they always show next to each other?

*Note: This is VERY simplified*

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add 'float: left' to the first, and remove 'clear: both' from the second, a la http://jsfiddle.net/L2JgX/3/